# .net maui app crashing at splash screen after changing package format to aab

Tags: maui

I switched to AAB format for my .NET MAUI Android app and I cannot run the app ever since. It builds and runs fine if I set it to APK. It also builds fine if I select AAB but opening the app crashes it immediately, what's more, I cannot even debug the issue because it doesn't even execute the first line of `OnCreate()` in `MainActivity.cs`

I have played around with all these settings, but it still always crashes at the splash screen.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Things to try: 1) Delete solution's .bin and .obj folders. 2) Manually delete the app from device or emulator. 3) Delete solution's hidden .vs folder.